# Bosch climate control 500 mini split. 2 heads in house 1 in basement. Can I power off head in basement when above freezing ty

Tags: heat-pump

Bosch climate 5000 series  2 heads in house 1 in basement. Can I power off the basement head when above freezing.  It won't  go bellow 60 degees

Comment: Can you? Should you? What does the manual say? What are you trying to achieve. Please [edit] to provide some more detail.

Comment: Congratulations! Either your new mini-split also has Audio abilities, or you mangled Bosch two different ways in one question. The latter seems more likely. You could [edit] to clear that up, and also provide an exact model number, which generally matters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is fairly clear if you have such a system., Though I grant that if you don't it isn't obvious that the inside heat sources/sinks have their own electronics to run their control and thermostat operations and the fan and vanes which direct the heated or cooled air. Like an AC, these can be turned off completely, in addition to thermostat control. The question is whether doing so for one "zone" (specifically the basement) while running others is a good option or not, and why. –

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is set the basement head on my Mitsubishi at a temperature which protects the pipes, and just let the thermostat cope with the rest. But if you want to save more power, it's just like any of the other heads; if you don't want to use it, just push its off button.

I'm actually in the process of developing a networked IR control setup for the Mitsubishi version, partly so I *can* have it turn on at temperatures below it's normal range. (Based on a number of open-source projects -- IR interface for Raspberry Pi, software to make it respond as a SmartThings home automation device, some homebrew stuff to deal with Mitsubishi's unusual IR command protocol and to simplify the behavior, ... Luckily I ordered the parts before the combination of "trade wars are easy to win" (no, they really aren't) and COVID-19 drove component prices through the ceiling.